# The output of scipy.signal.deconvolve() doesn't seem to be the expected result

Tags: python, scipy, signals

I got a problem with scipy.signal.deconvolve()
I tried the answer from [Understanding scipy deconvolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615034/understanding-scipy-deconvolve) but it didn't work.
here's my code:

```
n = 3

s = 240
p = np.linspace(-s*n, s*n, s*n*2)
g = mlab.normpdf(p, 0, s)
f1 = g/max(g)

s = 1920
p = np.linspace(-s*n, s*n, s*n*2)
g = mlab.normpdf(p, 0, s)
g1 = g/max(g)
```

let the signal be box-like

```
signal = g1
```

and use a gaussian filter

the filter should be shorter than the signal

the filter should be such that it's much bigger then zero everywhere

```
gauss = f1
print gauss.min()  # = 0.013 >> 0
```

calculate the convolution (np.convolve and scipy.signal.convolve identical)

the keywordargument mode="same" ensures that the convolution spans the same

shape as the input array.

filtered = scipy.signal.convolve(signal, gauss, mode='same')

```
filtered = np.convolve(signal, gauss, mode='same') 

deconv,  _ = deconvolve( filtered, gauss )
```

the deconvolution has n = len(signal) - len(gauss) + 1 points

```
n = len(signal)-len(gauss)+1
```

so we need to expand it by

```
s = (len(signal)-n)/2
```

on both sides.

```
deconv_res = np.zeros(len(signal))
deconv_res[s:len(signal)-s-1] = deconv
deconv = deconv_res
```

now deconv contains the deconvolution

expanded to the original shape (filled with zeros)

```
#### Plot #### 
fig , ax = plt.subplots(nrows=4, figsize=(6,7))

ax[0].plot(signal, color="#907700", label="original")
ax[1].plot(gauss, color="#68934e", label="gauss filter")
```

we need to divide by the sum of the filter window to get the convolution normalized to 1

```
ax[2].plot(filtered/np.sum(gauss), color="#325cab", label="convoluted")
ax[3].plot(deconv, color="#ab4232", label="deconvoluted")
# ax[3].set_yscale('log')

for i in range(len(ax)):
    ax[i].set_xlim([0, len(signal)])
    ax[i].legend(loc=1, fontsize=11)
    if i != len(ax)-1 :
        ax[i].set_xticklabels([])

plt.show()
```

[image]

The deconvoluted curve was suppose to be the same as the original gaussian.

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615034/understanding-scipy-deconvolve)
awww what should I write to have 30 symbols?