# Python how to deconvolve two Gaussian distributions

Tags: python, scipy, probability-distribution, deconvolution

The distribution of the sum of two normal independent random variables can be computed with aconvolution. I.e. **Z=X+Y** and *f_z = convolution(f_x, f_y)*.

I know that the convolution of two normal distributions is also a normal distribution with mean *mu_1 + mu_2* and variance *var_1 + var_2*. Now, I have a normal distribution *Z = X + Y* with N(0, std=5) and I also have the distribution *X* with N(20, std=4). I apply deconvolution to find the distribution Y, which should be N(-20, std=3). However when I apply `scipy.signal.deconvolve(Z, X)` it doesn't work as expected.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
from matplotlib.pyplot import draw, figure, show

dx = 1e-1
grid = np.arange(-20, 30, dx)
dist_X = scipy.stats.norm(loc=20, scale=4)
dist_Z = scipy.stats.norm(loc=0, scale=5)
# Dist Y should be Gaussian : N(loc=-20, scale=np.sqrt(25-16))

Z_signal = dist_Z.pdf(grid)
X_signal = dist_X.pdf(grid)

# Reconstructed distribution
Y_signal = scipy.signal.deconvolve(Z_signal, X_signal)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.plot(grid, Y_signal[1]/Y_signal[0], label=r'$Y$')
plt.plot(grid, X_signal, label=r'$X$')
plt.plot(grid, Z_signal, label=r'$Z$')
plt.legend(fontsize='16')
plt.grid(axis='x', color='0.95')
plt.grid(axis='y', color='0.95')
plt.ylabel(r'PDF', fontsize='20')
plt.xlabel(r'Distribution', fontsize='20')
draw()
show()
```

This is the result

[image: Y is the deconvolution(Z, X)]

Should I use another method? or am I missing something about this deconvolve tool? This case is pretty easy, but I intend to apply this method to other probability distributions which are not Gaussian.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the first return value from scipy.signal.deconvolve is the the deconvolved signal, and the second return value is the "remainder" that it could not remove. Since your divisor signal is the same length as the signal, it will return a length 1 deconvolved signal. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615034/understanding-scipy-deconvolve "The filter should be shorter than the signal"